# OpenGL texture appears to big on the screen

Tags: c++, opengl

Okay so I am working on a toy 2d engine. I initially used regular SDL_Surfaces for rendering and the built in SDL_Renderer. But I thought why not use OpenGL, get some experience with that.

But I am stuck now. I have a context and things are rendered to the screen, but it looks like the textures I am trying to display are way to big to fit in the screen. Like I only see a couple of pixels, but not really.

The texture class can be found here:

```
#include "texture.h"

Texture::Texture(std::string path, bool loadNow) {
    //Initialize texture ID
    mTextureID = 0;

    //Initialize texture dimensions
    width = 0;
    height = 0;

    this->path = path;

    if(loadNow) {
        loadTexture(path);
    }
}

Texture::~Texture() {
    freeTexture();
}

bool Texture::loadTexture(std::string path) {
    //Texture loading success
    loaded = false;

    SDL_Surface *image = IMG_Load(path.c_str());

    //Image loaded successfully
    if(image != NULL) {
        if((image->w & (image->w - 1)) == 0) {
            printf("Warning: image width not power of 2 -> %s\n", path.c_str());
        }
        if((image->h & (image->h - 1)) == 0) {
            printf("Warning: image height not power of 2 -> %s\n", path.c_str());
        }
        loaded = loadTextureFromPixels32(image, (GLuint)image->w, (GLuint)image->h);
    }

    //Report error
    if(!loaded) {
        printf( "Unable to load %s\n", path.c_str() );
    }


    return loaded;
}

bool Texture::loadTextureFromPixels32(SDL_Surface *image, GLuint width, GLuint height ) {
    //Free texture if it exists
    freeTexture();

    //Get texture dimensions
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;

    //Generate texture ID
    glGenTextures(1, &mTextureID);

    //Bind texture ID
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID);

    //Generate texture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->pixels);

    //Set texture parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    //Unbind texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    //Check for error
    GLenum error = glGetError();
    if(error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        printf("Error loading texture from %p pixels!\n", image->pixels);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void Texture::render(GLfloat x, GLfloat y) {
    if(loaded) {
        //If the texture exists
        if(mTextureID != 0) {
            GLfloat realX = x;// - (this->width / 2);
            GLfloat realY = y;// - (this->height / 2);

            //Remove any previous transformations
            glLoadIdentity();

            //Move to rendering point
            glTranslatef(realX, realY, 0.f);
            glClearDepth(1.0f); 

            //Set texture ID
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID);

            //Render textured quad
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glTexCoord2f( 0.f, 0.f ); glVertex2f(0.f,   0.f);
                glTexCoord2f( 1.f, 0.f ); glVertex2f(width, 0.f);
                glTexCoord2f( 1.f, 1.f ); glVertex2f(width, height);
                glTexCoord2f( 0.f, 1.f ); glVertex2f(0.f,   height);
            glEnd();
        }
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
}

GLuint Texture::getWidth() {
    return this->width;
}

GLuint Texture::getHeight() {
    return this->height;
}

void Texture::freeTexture() {
    //Delete texture
    if(mTextureID != 0) {
        glDeleteTextures(1, &mTextureID);
        mTextureID = 0;
    }

    width = 0;
    height = 0;
}
```

I am guessing the problem is here, but it could also be in how I initialize OpenGL so here is that:

```
void Main::initGL() {
    /* Request opengl 3.2 context.
     * SDL doesn't have the ability to choose which profile at this time of writing,
     * but it should default to the core profile */
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);

    /* Turn on double buffering with a 24bit Z buffer.
     * You may need to change this to 16 or 32 for your system */
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 32);

    glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(this->window);

    glViewport(0.0, 0.0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    glOrtho( 0.0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0 );

    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(0);

    //Initialize clear color
    glClearColor( 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f );

    //Enable texturing
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

    //Check for error
    GLenum error = glGetError();
    if(error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        printf("Error initializing OpenGL!\n");
    }
}
```

SDL is correctly initialized otherwise there wouldn't be anything on the screen. I am completely new to OpenGL so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the relevant source code as part of the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix ordinate `GL_TEXTURE_2D` stuff with `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE`, and enabling both is a very bad idea. You are using texcoords in the range [0,1], so you actually seem to  want to use `GL_TEXTURE_2D`. You should rewrite your texture code to use that, and dropt those rectangle textures entirely.

The next thing is that your projection setup is wrong. Your `glOrtho` call has no effect since you completely overwrite this by loading the identity matrix a few lines later. You should make yourself familiar with the stae machine approach the GL is using. As your matrices are set up currently, you draw a *huge* quad with most of it completely ot of the screen.

Now that part is completely strange:

```
/* Request opengl 3.2 context.
 * SDL doesn't have the ability to choose which profile at this time of writing,
 * but it should default to the core profile */
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 2);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);
```

This code is will never create a core profile, because core profiles *didn't even exist* in GL2.1, they were introduced in GL3.2. It is unclear what SDL version you are using, but modern SDL is capable of selecting the profile.

However, your code is using *completely outdated ande deprecated* OpenGL, there is no way this will work with a core profile. If you learn OpenGL in this decade, I'd strongly suggest that you forget about all that and start with some documentation/tutorial on modern GL, and actually use a core profiel.

Comment: Okay, I fixed that GL version. And I removed the identity matrix setup functions. I have a hard time finding decent documentation on OpenGL, if you know something I would really appreciate a link. One problem though, now I am only getting a purple screen, the texture that I am loading is an image with purple in it, but it's not completely purple.

Comment: @blackwolf123333: regarding modern GL, the [arcsynthesis](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) and [open.gl](http://open.gl) tutorials are quite often recommended.